# Elegant way to pass a "partial closure"?

Tags: ios, swift, function, uiview, closures

In my `ViewController`, I am setting up multiple so-called `PanelControl`s.
These `PanelControl`s are initialized with a title, `UISlider` and information, what property of another `UIView` called `ViewToEdit` to change with that slider (`ControlPanel` has a reference to it). 
It is always one single property of type `CGFloat` or `UIColor`.

I want to be able to pass a property (not a value) of `ViewToEdit` when initializing a `PanelControl`.

So I wanna use it like this:

```
PanelControl(title: "doesnt matter", propertyToEdit: ViewToEdit.propertyToEdit)
```

And `PanelControl` would implement it like this:

```
class PanelControl: UIView {
   ...
   func sliderChanged(slider: UISlider) {
       propertyToEdit = slider.value
   } 
}
```

*please not that the above code is just my fantasy and doesn't actually work. It just illustrates my desired usage.*

This way I could create many instances of `PanelControl` and pass each one different information on which property of `ViewToEdit` they control.

### I have tried:

- Using a closure, but that does not fit because it is not a complete statement I want to pass. Rather a *part* of a statement. So `viewToEdit.propertyToEdit = ...` with the right side of that statement set by `PanelControl` when executing it.
- Literally passing it `ViewToEdit.propertyToEdit` but that obviously makes no sense as well.

*What to I do?*

Comment: can you pass a Dictionary? key will be the property to edit and value the value for that property

Comment: Passing a Dictionary to `ViewToEdit` instead of directly manipulation it in `PanelControl`? I find that rather inelegant and what type would the Key be?

Comment: I mean if you have a predefined number of properties that can be changed

Comment: That is a possible solution. But it sacrifices flexibilty (when I want to add a new property to edit). And is error-prone, because it has to match an abstract number in a dictionary.

Comment: Why don't you use enums with associated values ?

Comment: You can add a closure to your class and pass self as closure parameter to configure whaever you need inside of that closure

Comment: @ReinierMelian Please elaborate

Answer (score 0):

How about using key paths:

```
class PanelControl: UIView {
    let changer: (Float) -> Void

    init<T: AnyObject>(title: String, object: T, property: ReferenceWritableKeyPath<T, Float>) {
        changer = { object[keyPath: property] = $0 }
    }

    func sliderChanged(slider: UISlider) {
        changer(slider.value)
    }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
PanelControl(title: "doesnt matter", object: myViewModel, property: \ViewToEdit.propertyToEdit)
```